# RAM usage doesn't add up? (Free+used < total)

Tags: ubuntu, memory

Lately I've been noticing that my monitoring script which reads from /proc/meminfo and /proc/<pid> has been showing odd readings, where several hundred MB seem to be missing. htop is showing the same discrepancy:

```
CPU: 36.9% sys:  7.6% low:  0.0%                        Tasks: 123; 1 running
Mem:1750M used:1568M buffers:20M cache:87M              Load average: 0.90 1.33 1.33 
Swp:1787M used:184M                                     Uptime: 1 day, 00:28:22
  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
 3455 rena       20   0 1221M  312M 20464 S 14.0 17.8  1h20:26 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 1428 root       20   0  327M  100M  6236 S  7.0  5.7  1h28:52 /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nol
14012 rena       20   0  630M 26400  5264 S  0.0  1.5  0:14.20 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/sonata --toggle
 2562 rena       20   0  914M 21100 10904 S  0.0  1.2  3:59.50 xfce4-terminal --role "Terminal" --hide-menubar -
 2492 rena       20   0  379M 20528  3312 S  0.0  1.1  0:03.53 pcmanfm --desktop --profile lubuntu
```

Memory used is 1568M, but the top 5 processes aren't using anywhere near that: 312+100+26+21+20+20(buffers)+87(cache) = 586M. So 982M are missing somewhere?

OS is Lubuntu 12.04 AMD64.

Contents of `/proc/meminfo`:

```
MemTotal:        1792540 kB
MemFree:           67824 kB
Buffers:           17084 kB
Cached:           109624 kB
SwapCached:        69600 kB
Active:           436880 kB
Inactive:         245756 kB
Active(anon):     402348 kB
Inactive(anon):   169616 kB
Active(file):      34532 kB
Inactive(file):    76140 kB
Unevictable:       13456 kB
Mlocked:           13456 kB
SwapTotal:       1830908 kB
SwapFree:        1632380 kB
Dirty:                40 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        515492 kB
Mapped:            46852 kB
Shmem:              3308 kB
Slab:             875752 kB
SReclaimable:      19108 kB
SUnreclaim:       856644 kB
KernelStack:        2688 kB
PageTables:        19468 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     2727176 kB
Committed_AS:    1741500 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      285612 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359436336 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     1551232 kB
DirectMap2M:      282624 kB
```

Head of slabtop (by size):

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 1859056 / 1873931 (99.2%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 115960 / 115960 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 76 / 108 (70.4%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 906258.20K / 909988.65K (99.6%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.49K / 8.00K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
1640475 1640475 100%    0.53K 109365       15    874920K idr_layer_cache
  4941   4628  93%    0.86K    549        9      4392K ext4_inode_cache
 19068  13243  69%    0.19K    908       21      3632K dentry
  6034   5325  88%    0.55K    431       14      3448K inode_cache
 20272  20272 100%    0.14K    724       28      2896K sysfs_dir_cache
```

Comment: Could you run a `slabtop -s c` to see what's in there? (SUnreclaim looks high in your meminfo.)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wmJSkx4S
that does add up to about 982M, but why? o.O

Comment: Any unusual modules or programs running? That idr_layer_cache thing is very strange.

Comment: Nothing sticks out in lsmod. I have a funny feeling the radeon driver is responsible though... it's given me a lot of grief already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a confirmed bug on launchpad. It's also affecting my system.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1047566

Answer (score -3):

This might be due to [Page Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). If that is the case, [forcing the kernel to drop the page caches](http://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches) will free a significant amount of memory.

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Comment: The output in the question indicates the cache size is somewhat small ( ~100MB ).

Comment: That doesn't appear to have had any effect.

Comment: Yes indeed, the effect will be negligent if the size of the dirty cached pages is small. This does not seem to be the problem in your case. My wrong -did not examine thoroughly your /proc/meminfo.